# drm_msm kernel compile failed,mutiple definition

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, android-kernel

```
after enable DRM_MSM kernel config, it show error when build kernel,
techpack/display/msm/sde_io_util.c:418: multiple definition of \`msm_dss_clk_set_rate'
drivers/gpu/drm/msm/disp/dpu1/dpu_io_util.o:drivers/gpu/drm/msm/disp/dpu1/dpu_io_util.c:60: first defined here
alot errors like this,whole error log is here
https://pastebin.com/tpd6KM4y


how can i fix this? any suggestions ,thanks
kernel version 4.19.157 ,https://github.com/suisuyy/lenovo-j607f-kernel
```

how to fix it
what is techpack,why it conflict with msm drm

Comment: i try to enable drmmsm because when i start xserver,it show error :failed to load driver: msm_drm

Comment: was it an error or just info message?

Comment: its multiple definition error, i have give up, drm_msm seems not a good idea for android kernel